# UIScrollview scrolls back down when tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a weird issue which I'm sure someone can help fix easily. I have a UIImageView within a UIScrollview which I'm able to scroll up to the top. I have paging enabled and it's working as expected except for one problem. After I scroll the image all the way to the top and it snaps, as soon as I touch anywhere in the UIScrollView, it automatically scrolls the UIImageView back down.  Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by playing with the UIScrollview's content size.

Comment: Mark your question as answered by yourself :P